# Creating an array and a loop using Javascript with delays and actions

Tags: javascript

I need help creating an array and a loop.  I am not sure how to include the two actions I need for both the mouseover and click for all 6 buttons I need to cycle through.  Here is a sample of the code with the delays and two of the buttons.  The buttons have other area's where they are have actions to the mouse over and click so I am including both so the transition looks better.

I am using the delay to slowly transition from one button to the next but am having difficulty to get it to loop.

```
var delay1=5800//2 seconds
var delay2=6000//6 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#mc_button_hitID_2").mouseover();
}, delay1)

setTimeout(function(){
  $("#mc_button_hitID_2").click();
  //your code to be executed after 1 seconds
}, delay2)
```

Comment: BTW, 2 seconds is 2000 milliseconds, not 5800 (thats 5.8 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you want to hover and click the buttons via javascript. If you are looking to create a nice transition I suggest you take a look at [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/jump-start-js/)

Otherwise, a solution to your query might be something like this.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeA9r/)

```
//jquery ready function
$(function(){
    var btns = $('button'); //selector for all your buttons
    var count = 0; //var to keep track of progress
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
        if(count === btns.length){
            clearInterval(loop);
        }else{
            //do your stuff.
            var delay1=5800//2 seconds
            var delay2=6000//6 seconds

            setTimeout(function(){
              $(btns[count]).mouseover();
            }, delay1)

            setTimeout(function(){
              $(btns[count]).click();
              //your code to be executed after 1 seconds
            }, delay2)
        }
        count++;
    },6000) //you probably need some delay between each button

    ///just some testing code to know that we are really interacting with the buttons
    $('button').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
            console.log('clicked ' + $(this).html());
        })
        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            console.log('mouseover ' + $(this).html());
        })
    })
})
```